# Dell XPS 13 9310 bluetooth wont find anything

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, 20.10, xps

Just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my brand new XPS 13. Bluetooth is active and it wont find anything. There is one time where it found "Audio Device" and "Unknown" but I can't even click.

I tried `bluetoothctl` with `power on`, `scan on` and etc, but it won't find anything.

I don't even know which bluetooth device my Dell uses, because it won't appear on lspci or lsusb:

```
lz@xps13:~$ lspci
0000:00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9a14 (rev 01)
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a49 (rev 01)
0000:00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a03 (rev 01)
0000:00:06.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 09ab
0000:00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9a23 (rev 01)
0000:00:07.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9a27 (rev 01)
0000:00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a0d (rev 01)
0000:00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a13 (rev 01)
0000:00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a1b (rev 01)
0000:00:0d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a1d (rev 01)
0000:00:0e.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller
0000:00:12.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device a0fc (rev 20)
0000:00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device a0ed (rev 20)
0000:00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device a0ef (rev 20)
0000:00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a0e8 (rev 20)
0000:00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a0e9 (rev 20)
0000:00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device a0e0 (rev 20)
0000:00:19.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a0c5 (rev 20)
0000:00:19.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a0c6 (rev 20)
0000:00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a0b8 (rev 20)
0000:00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a0b3 (rev 20)
0000:00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device a0a8 (rev 20)
0000:00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a082 (rev 20)
0000:00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device a0c8 (rev 20)
0000:00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device a0a3 (rev 20)
0000:00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a0a4 (rev 20)
0000:55:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Device 1101 (rev 01)
0000:56:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5260 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
10000:e0:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9a09 (rev 01)
10000:e1:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Toshiba Corporation Device 011a

lz@xps13:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0c45:672a Microdia Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 22b8:2e25 Motorola PCS XT1650
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 27c6:533c Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. FingerPrint
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I'm on `5.10.0-051000rc6-lowlatency` because the one that comes with ubuntu 20.04 has problems with sleep and other things.

How do I know which bluetooth device I'm using?

PS: I also have no wifi yet, seems like the driver for `Network controller: Qualcomm Device 1101 (rev 01)` is not ready yet.

I tried ubuntu 20.10 but I get error on installation, tried many times. But I guess the problem is more kernel related.

```
[bluetooth]# list
Controller 00:00:00:00:5A:AD xps13 [default]
```

**UPDATE:**

```
lz@xps13:~$ sudo dmesg | grep -i blue
[sudo] password for lz: 
[   37.837663] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   37.837675] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   37.837678] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   37.837680] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   37.837683] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   37.854802] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[   37.854804] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[   37.854804] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[   37.854810] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[   37.854810] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[   37.854814] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[   37.854845] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[   37.854863] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[   37.854866] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[   37.854866] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
[   37.854870] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Marvell registered
[   37.969110] Bluetooth: hci0: setting up ROME/QCA6390
[   37.974178] Bluetooth: Received HCI_IBS_WAKE_ACK in tx state 0
[   38.275421] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA Product ID   :0x00000010
[   38.275422] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA SOC Version  :0x400a0200
[   38.275422] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA ROM Version  :0x00000200
[   38.275423] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA Patch Version:0x00000d2b
[   38.275424] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA controller version 0x02000200
[   38.275425] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA Downloading qca/htbtfw20.tlv
[   38.275588] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for qca/htbtfw20.tlv failed with error -2
[   38.275590] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA Failed to request file: qca/htbtfw20.tlv (-2)
[   38.275591] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA Failed to download patch (-2)
[   38.985832] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   38.985833] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   38.985837] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   46.210793] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   46.210798] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   46.210800] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

**After inserting the firmware:**

```
lz@xps13:~$ sudo dmesg | grep -i blue
[   10.126340] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   10.126356] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   10.126360] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   10.126362] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   10.126364] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   10.168251] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[   10.168252] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[   10.168253] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[   10.168261] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[   10.168262] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[   10.168271] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[   10.168303] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[   10.168321] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[   10.168324] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[   10.168325] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
[   10.168327] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Marvell registered
[   10.276703] Bluetooth: hci0: setting up ROME/QCA6390
[   12.322211] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   12.322212] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   12.322216] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   12.685060] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc00 tx timeout
[   21.069061] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading QCA version information failed (-110)
```

**UPDATE:**

```
lz@xps13:~$ sudo dmesg | grep -i blue
[sudo] password for lz: 
[   22.779705] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   22.779720] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   22.779723] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   22.779725] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   22.779728] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   22.790061] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[   22.790063] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[   22.790064] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[   22.790070] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[   22.790070] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[   22.790074] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[   22.790096] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[   22.790126] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[   22.790130] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[   22.790130] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
[   22.790134] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Marvell registered
[   22.931800] Bluetooth: hci0: setting up ROME/QCA6390
[   22.939205] Bluetooth: hci0: Frame reassembly failed (-84)
[   23.245423] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA Product ID   :0x00000010
[   23.245424] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA SOC Version  :0x400a0200
[   23.245425] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA ROM Version  :0x00000200
[   23.245425] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA Patch Version:0x00000d2b
[   23.245427] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA controller version 0x02000200
[   23.245428] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA Downloading qca/htbtfw20.tlv
[   24.118016] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA Downloading qca/htnv20.bin
[   24.118039] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for qca/htnv20.bin failed with error -2
[   24.118041] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA Failed to request file: qca/htnv20.bin (-2)
[   24.118044] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA Failed to download NVM (-2)
[   24.155330] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   24.155332] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   24.155336] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   39.842936] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   39.842943] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   39.842946] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  136.016876] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c1a tx timeout
[  138.064522] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c3a tx timeout
[  140.112331] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c1a tx timeout
[  142.160092] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c52 tx timeout
[  146.255507] Bluetooth: hci0: failed to disable LE scan: status 0x1f
[  146.255555] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2042 tx timeout
```

Comment: I guess the BT is not supported by Linux kernel. As simple as that.

Comment: @Pilot6 but sometimes if I leave for too long, it recognizes some real devices but I can't conect. So the support exists but is broken. How can I know which driver it's using and which device?

Comment: Look into `dmesg`. That can give some clue. But you won't find any "drivers" in the meaning you can install them. Start with `dmesg | grep -i blue`.

Comment: @Pilot6 please look at my update

Comment: Have you downloaded the latest bios updates for your system? https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/xps-13-9310-laptop/drivers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see there is no firmware for the Bluetooth device.

You can install it this way. Run in a terminal

```
sudo apt install git
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
sudo cp linux-firmware/qca/htbtfw20.tlv /lib/firmware/qca
sudo cp linux-firmware/qca/htnv20.bin /lib/firmware/qca
```

Then reboot.

**Note:** Ubuntu 20.10 has this firmware initially.

**Update:** Now you have another problem

```
[   12.685060] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc00 tx timeout
[   21.069061] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading QCA version information failed (-110)
```

This is related to the kernel driver. I suggest installing the 5.8 kernel by running

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04-edge
```

and rebooting.

Your current kernel will stay intact, you will always be able to revert it.

Comment: Please take a look at my update. After inserting the firmware and reboting, my bluetooth wont turn on. Also `lz@xps13:~$ sudo bluetoothctl
[sudo] password for lz: 
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# power on
No default controller available`

Comment: Please update output of `dmesg | grep -i blue` after you added the firmware. And add infromation to your question, not to comments.

Comment: I updated my question with dmesg after adding the firmware

Comment: And I updated the answer.

Comment: Installing and reboting didnt change my kernel, still on `5.10.0-051000rc6-lowlatency`

Comment: You are using an unsupported mainline release candidate kernel. Boot with an Ubuntu kernel using grub menu.

Comment: And you also need `qca/htnv20.bin`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, 5.8 kernel worked. Do you think things will be fixed on 5.11?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using mainline kernels with Ubuntu unless there is no other choice. Did you try the 5.4? It could work as well.

Comment: on the kernel that came with ubuntu, sleep and touchscreen wouldn't work, but they work on 5.8 thankfully. I'll wait for another ubuntu kernel then

Comment: So you can stick with the 5.8. It will get updates the way you installed it.