# How to securely get a driver for my bluetooth?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, bluetooth, atheros

This answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1299960/613425 instructs me to do the following:

```
sudo apt install git
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
sudo cp linux-firmware/qca/htbtfw20.tlv /lib/firmware/qca
```

kernel's git is not a bad place to get a firmware. But is there a better way of at least knowing this is the official firmware from atheros?

He says that it's included in Ubuntu 20.10. Is there a way to download this from Ubuntu's repo over https?

I'm looking for minimal security. Obviously using a proprietary firmware is already bad but it's what I got

Comment: This is the official `linux-firmware` kernel git. You can use https as well. https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you do:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.190_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot. You should be all set.

Comment: Well, I think getting a single file from the official kernel git is a bit better than install another full `linux-firmware` package from another Ubuntu release. It can theoretically break things. And also firmware upgrades won't come normally, because of the version.